Как протестировать телеграм бота под нагрузкой, без использования реальных аккаунтов?
Я пишу телеграмм бота на Python aiogram3 для игры в квиз. Мне нужно протестировать как он будет работать под нагрузкой из нескольких десятков/сотен пользователей, будут ли задержки в отсылке сообщений и т.п. Но я нигде не могу найти информацию, как это сделать. Единственное что нашел, это информацию что Телеграмм предоставляет возможность как-то создавать этих тестовых пользователей, но о том, как это сделать, ни слова...
https://core.telegram.org/api/auth#test-accounts

Реализовал тестирование на основе статьи на хабре.
В ней все подробно расписано, как создавать тестовых пользователей, проверять, что их id свободны, и удалять после тестирования.
Метод рабочий, пробуйте.

Спасибо, я читал эту статью, но к сожалению почти ничего в ней не понял, по крайней мере то, что касается реализации в коде. Наверное, моего уровня программирования еще не хватает для понимания.

P.S. А вы как смогли зайти в выделенную тестовую среду Телеграм? Я пробовал все перечисленные методы, но ничего не получилось(

Чтобы запустить бота в тестовой среде, нужно к токену добавить /test

Ну и получить токен в тестовой среде. У меня айфон, сработало долгое нажатие на иконку настроек в мобильном приложении. В общем все, как написано в статье. Код действительно сложноват на первый взгляд. Но разобраться можно.

В том и проблема, что у меня нет айфона(
Для десктопного приложения указанный там способ не работает, а для андроида его вообще нет...
Тестовых "клиентов" в Pyrogram, у меня получается создать, но проблема как раз в том, что взаимодействуют они только с сущностями из тестового пространства, а войти в него у меня не получается.
P.S. Спасибо за ответ! Приятно осознавать, что код и правда сложноват, а не просто я такой тупой)

Протестировал у себя на десктопной версии под ubuntu. В win такая же схема. Нужно зайти в настройки -> мой аккаунт. Далее удерживая нажатыми ALT+SHIFT кликаете по кнопке "добавить пользователя" ПРАВОЙ кнопкой. Появляется попап с вариантом добавить тестового пользователя. Под ним уже регистрируете нового бота в тестовом пространстве и получаете токен, который сможете использовать. Если все получится, отметьте, пожалуйста мой ответ, как принятый.
